# google sheets - how reset data labels that have been changed manually?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to reset data labels that have been changed manually in google sheets bars chart, and I can't find it in any of the options of the "chart editor". I always get back the last numbers that was inserted manually, and not the original data from the table at question.

I tried to edit it in the "Setup" section, under the "Series" and pick the data range again, but couldn't find a way that works. maybe I'm missing something.
the only way I can think of, of course, is building the same graph again, but this is not smart when I have so many graphs to update
help pls

Comment: charts are buggy. you may need to remove the chart and create it again

Answer (score 1):

select the given single data label you want to reset, then right click it and choose "Format data point" > "Revert to default"

haven't found a way to revert multiple at the same time, might need to recreate the chart for that